# flutter webview select file in form option doesn't work on Android,works on iOS

Tags: flutter, webview, flutter-dependencies

i am using webview_flutter dependency and firebase messaging service
i want to upload files/photos to url but it is not working in Android, i tried adding permissions in androidManifest file (main). and permission_handler dependency,
when i start my app it asks for PUSH NOTIFICATIONS permission but doesn't ask's for Storage/camera etc. I am using init state for permission handler.
[image]

my code

main.dart

```
import 'package:auction_wind/homepage.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

import 'notificationservice/local_notification_service.dart';

Future<void> backgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  print(message.data.toString());
  print(message.notification?.title);
}

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(backgroundHandler);
  LocalNotificationService.initialize();
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
      .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
          AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
      ?.requestPermission();

  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Made by Shriramgupta8141@gmail.com',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Homepage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Homepage.dart

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:connectivity_plus/connectivity_plus.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

import 'demo.dart';
import 'notificationservice/local_notification_service.dart';

bool netState = true;

class Homepage extends StatefulWidget {
  const Homepage({super.key});

  @override
  State<Homepage> createState() => _HomepageState();
}

class _HomepageState extends State<Homepage> {
  late WebViewController _controller = WebViewController();

  final Completer<WebViewController> _controllerCompleter =
      Completer<WebViewController>();
  Future CheckConnection() async {
    final connectionStatus = await (Connectivity().checkConnectivity());
    if (connectionStatus == ConnectivityResult.none) {
      setState(() {
        netState = false;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        netState = true;
      });
    }
  }

  Future CheckPermission() async {
    var grant = await Permission.storage.request();
    var grant2 = await Permission.camera.request();

    if (grant.isGranted) {
      //
    }
    if (grant.isDenied) {
      openAppSettings();
      //
    }
    print('ASDFAASFASF');
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    CheckPermission();
    CheckConnection();

    // 1. This method call when app in terminated state and you get a notification
    // when you click on notification app open from terminated state and you can get notification data in this method

    FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then(
      (message) {
        print("FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage");
        if (message != null) {
          print("New Notification");
          if (message.data['_id'] != null) {
            Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => Demo(
                  id: message.data['_id'],
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
        }
      },
    );

// 2. This method only call when App in forground it mean app must be opened
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen(
      (message) {
        print("FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen");
        if (message.notification != null) {
          print(message.notification!.title);
          print(message.notification!.body);
          print("message.data11 ${message.data}");
          LocalNotificationService.createanddisplaynotification(message);
        }
      },
    );

    // 3. This method only call when App in background and not terminated(not closed)
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen(
      (message) {
        print("FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen");
        if (message.notification != null) {
          print(message.notification!.title);
          print(message.notification!.body);
          print("message.data22 ${message.data['_id']}");
        }
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () => _goBack(context),
      child: Scaffold(
        body: netState
            ? Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
                child: WebViewWidget(
                    controller: _controller
                      ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
                      ..setNavigationDelegate(
                        NavigationDelegate(
                          onPageFinished: (String url) {
                            _controller.runJavaScript(
                                "document.getElementsByClassName('logo me-lg-4')[0].remove();" +
                                    "document.getElementsByClassName('cookies-card bg--default text-center cookies--dark radius--10px')[0].remove();");
                          },
                        ),
                      )
                      ..loadRequest(Uri.parse(
                          'https://www.filemail.com/share/upload-file'))),
              )
            : const Center(
                child: Text(
                  'No internet Conncetion',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ),
        bottomNavigationBar:bottomNavBar();
```

pubspec.yaml

```
name: auction_wind
description: Made by Shriramgupta8141@gmail.com
# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev


version: 1.0.0+3

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.19.4 <3.0.0'


dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  webview_flutter: 
  connectivity_plus: ^2.3.5
  firebase_core: ^1.19.2
  firebase_messaging: ^12.0.0
  flutter_local_notifications: ^9.7.0
  firebase_core_platform_interface: 4.5.1
  marquee: ^2.2.3
  image_picker: ^0.8.7+2
  permission_handler: ^10.2.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.12.0"
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/icon.png"
```

(main) AndroidManifest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.auctionwind.auction_wind">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

   <application
        android:label="Auction Wind"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Help is appriciated.

Comment: checkout stackoverflow.com/a/77155112/1979347 for fixing file upload issue on Android using webview